# Instantiate a interface type variable with a value

Tags: java

I recived some tasks as homework after I did just 1h of course about interfaces, did them but this gave me real problems:
An interface `I1` having: method: `int read();`
A class `A` implements the interface and containing: the method `int read()` that read a value from the keyboard;
A class B containing:a variable `c` type `I1`, a constructor with one parameter for assigning value for `c`, a method `afis()` that display the `summ` of the numbers.

This is what I did so far, but I'm stuck here, how can i assign a value to `c` and add it with the `n1` from `A` class?

```
package toDo2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public interface i1 {
    int read();
}

class A implements i1 {

    public int read() {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce the value for n1"));
        return n1;
    }

}

class B {

    int sum;
    i1 c;

    B(i1 c) {

    }   
}

class toDo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        B n1 = new B(/*here must be the value of c which is i1 type*/);



    }

}
```

Comment: This is confusing. What does the main look like so we can see how you want to use these classes?

Comment: main is empty right now. Main class that will instantiate the B. This is the only task for main().

Comment: I think you will assign this.c to c in the B constructor. But since I can't see the main I don't know what you will do with B.

Comment: Ok i ll add the main right now, but it is empty

Comment: Voted to close for lack of clarity as demonstrated in the answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, you need to create an instance of class `A` in your main method because it is so far the only class implementing interface `i1`:

```
class B {
    int sum;
    i1 c;

    B(i1 c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}

class toDo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        B n1 = new B(new A());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Also, class B won't be aware of specific implementation of its `c` field - it will be able to invoke method `int read()` defined in your interface.

Comment: Thanks, the ```B n1 = new B(new A());``` works but i have to make the sum in ```B```class, the sum between 2 numbers, i guess ```c``` would not be a number and i can`t figure out what is the scound number

Comment: It seems you need to get clarifications on this task with your teacher, and get to know which numbers need to be summed up in your hometask.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
B n1 = new B(new A());
```

Basically your `class A` is of type `I1` because it's implementing `I1`.

Here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
        I1 a = new A();
        a.read(); //this call will initiate taking input
        B n1 = new B(a);
        int sum = n1.sum(a.getFirstNumber(), a.getSecondNumber());
        System.out.println(sum);
     }
}

interface I1 {
    void read();
    int getFirstNumber();
    int getSecondNumber();
}

class A implements I1 {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    public void read() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n1 = in.nextInt();
        n2 = in.nextInt();
    }

    public int getFirstNumber() {
        return n1;
    }

    public int getSecondNumber() {
        return n2;
    }

}

class B {

    I1 c;

    B(I1 c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public int sum(int n1, int n2)  {
        return n1+n2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works as i said to the other nice guy under u, but I have to do the sum between 2 numbers in B class and if i do and other int read, the one from A class is not called anywhere

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your effort, but i must respect the tasks 100%, so just the int read() in interface and just the called int read in class A...

Comment: I think this platform is for help not for " tasks 100%", you can tweak this as per your requirement. Help is already given to you.